# WPF C# - Complex Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a very complex databinding I want to accomplish here using the below:

- 2 SQL CE tables named `mainTable` and `secondaryTable`
- 1 [Fluidkit ElementFlow control](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) named `myElmntFlow`
- 2 UserControls named `myUsrCtrl` and `otherUsrCtrl`

All of the above are already created and implemented but the UserControls are populated into the `myElmntFlow` control's items list programmatically through lenghty backgroundworker code that does take a good bit of time to run when the number of items to enter is > 20.

This is how they get created as of now:
The backgroundworker loops through each row of `mainTable` and adds the `myUsrCtrl` control to the list of items in `myElmntFlow` if the value of the row in column "Selected" = "'Yes'".

Then, it modifies the content of the newly added `myUsrCtrl` as such: it adds a `otherUsrCtrl` into the `myUsrCtrl`'s stackpanel (named `stckPanel`) for each row in `secondaryTable` where the value of the column "FullName " = the value of the same column of the `mainTable` row we used to created the `myUsrCtrl` control.

And then populates the `otherUsrCtrl`'s sevaral labels with the value of the `secondaryTable` row looked at at the moment.

Very confusing but it is a complex scenario. Let's use an example:

- In `mainTable`, the row #4 has the FullName value of "Chad Jones" and
  also has the Selected value of "Yes".
- A new instance of the `myUsrCtrl` control is added to the
  `myElmntFlow`'s list of items as such: 
  `myElmntFlow.Items.Add(myUsrCtrl)`;
- The newly added myUsrCtrl control has a stackpanel (`stckPanel`)
- We filter the `secondaryTable` where the FullName = "Chad Jones"
- For each row in the now filtered `secondaryTable`, we add a new
  instance of `otherUsrCtrl` to the previously created `myUsrCtrl`'s
  `stckPanel` control
- The different labels in the `otherUsrCtrl` are populated with the values of the
  row in `secondaryTable`

Can this possibly be converted into a DataBinding within the XAML of the controls as I want to implement several features later on (such as a nice SearchBox with autocomplete) that would be quite poor if they were to be coded behind by writing hundreds of line to tell which data to filter, sort , take , compare etc...

I wrote this as clearly as I could, just hope it's understandable.

PS: I would like to keep my SQL structure as the data is going to become quite consequent over time and I believe that the SQL is the way to go when manipulating thousands of lines.

Comment: Why are you mannually adding to myElmntFlow.Items rather then binding to a collection?  You are creating the myUsrCtrl in the background?

Comment: My usercontrols are already created but are called upon as new instances in teh C# code behind. Your first point is why i asked the questionin the first place, I want to change it to a Binding model but I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: If ElementFlow is not a control this binds to a collection (a repeater control) then consider another design.  If it binds to a collection then do so.  If binding to a collection is new to you then start with a simple ListView control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very confusing scenario, it's just made confusing by the complex handling that goes on there. It can indeed be made much easier using bindings and MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) so please take some time to read about the basics of that. There are a ton of tutorials and introductory materials on the web, a simple search will give you more than enough to go on.

When you're comfortable with the concepts, all you need is to transform the data into a sequence of objects (no matter how you go about it), then use an ItemsControl to represent the UI for a list of items. Use DataTemplates to specify how each item should be displayed, binding elements in the DataTemplate to the properties of each item. These things can be nested so you can have ItemsControls in your DataTemplates which use other DataTemplates etc.

In order to represent a collection of items bound to an ItemsControl look at using an ICollectionView which will help tremendously with filtering/sorting/etc.

Sorry about the very broad strokes but it is a pretty broad question. If you need more specific help I'll gladly add more.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. While I don't get more specific answers, I am going to read up on both of them. I've found a good link for anybody out there who wants some kind of "tutorial" : blog.lab49.com/archives/2650

Comment: OK, i've looked up the databinding and it seems to be working for me thanks!